# Create a list of datetime strings with 10 seconds between

Tags: python, datetime

I want to create a list of datetimes that increment by 10 seconds. The format should be consistent with the following:

```
start = '2016_02_23_14_32_50'
end = '2016_02_24_17_16_00'
```

I'm aware that I could use deltatime but I'm unsure what the correct implementation would be.

Comment: Did you read this: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta

Answer (score 2):

First, convert your string to a `datetime` object with `strptime`. Then you can increment it by 10 seconds with `timedelta`.

```
import datetime

start = '2016_02_23_14_32_50'
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(start, '%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S')
dt += datetime.timedelta(seconds=10)
```

Comment: Ah fantastic. and then i can put it in a while loop that says `while != final_time`